# Strange "directive is not allowed" at proxy_set_header

Tags: nginx

The NGINX conf bellow is not working on `nginx -t`:

```
location ~ ^/ETC[0-9](?:\.json|\.(?<ext>csv))?/?$ {
  if ($ext) {
     set $extOpt  '&csv=1'; 
     proxy_set_header Accept 'text/csv'; # BUG HERE!
  }
  rewrite ^/ETC1               /rpc/etc?q=v1$extOpt;     break;
  rewrite ^/ETC[2-9]           /rpc/etc?q=other$extOpt;  break;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
}
```

> nginx: [emerg] "proxy_set_header" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/...:17
>
> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

I not see where the problem (see e. g. [nginx/wiki](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/))... Well, if the `if` is not valid, there are a way to express **conditional `proxy_set_header`?**

---

### NOTES

- Not make sense because when using direct `proxy_set_header Accept 'text/csv';` instead it in the `if ($ext)` block, it works fine.
- It is similar but not a duplicate of [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35259076/287948).

Comment: The `proxy_set_header` directive is not allowed within an `if` block, only the `http`, `server`, and `location` blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) and notice the "Context" line in the summary.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith, seems the answer (the "context" show syntax at guide)!... So, no way to **conditional** `proxy_set_header `?

Comment: Use a `map`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845155/set-custom-header-in-nginx-config-and-pass-it-to-gunicorn/35846083#35846083).